# Firebase Emulator - Functions - FieldValue undefined

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have an app that uses Firestore and in the app I have a `functions` folder containing my Firebase functions. When I deploy, everything is working, but in my test environment anytime I access `FieldValue` from `admin.firestore` it comes back as undefined.

Example:

```
time: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
```

> error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'serverTimestamp')

```
console.log(admin.firestore.FieldValue)
```

> undefined

my directory structure is as so:

project

- app (react typescript)

  - functions

    - package.json
  - src
- package.json

package for my host app:

```
"firebase": "^9.17.0",
```

package for functions

```
"firebase-admin": "^11.2.0",
"firebase-functions": "^4.4.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

You should import `FieldValue` in one of these ways:

```
import { FieldValue } from 'firebase-admin/firestore'
```

or

```
const { FieldValue } = require ("firebase-admin/firestore");
```

And then use directly `FieldValue` so:

```
console.log(FieldValue)
```